# rails 4 nested form fields_for are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I just started learning Rails 4.2. **The problem is that one field in the form is not being displayed.**

I have restaurant, category and a dish. While creating a dish, the category and restaurant will also be inputted via /dishes/new.

**Expected behaviour:** Dish, Category and Restaurant fields are displayed.

**Actual behaviour:** Only Dish and Category fields are displayed.

Here are my models

### models/restaurant.rb

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  has_many :dishes, :through => :categories
end
```

### models/category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :dishes
end
```

### models/dish.rb

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  validates :name, :price, :category, :restaurant, :presence => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :restaurant, :category
end
```

---

### dish controller

```
  def new
    # I think this is where
    # I am making a mistake
    @dish = Dish.new
    category = @dish.build_category
    restaurant = category.build_restaurant
  end

  def create
    @dish = Dish.new(dish_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dish.save
        .... # default stuff #
      end
    end
  end

# strong params
  def dish_params
      params.require(:dish).permit(:name, :description, :price, restaurant_attributes: [:name], category_attributes: [:name])
  end
```

---

### Dishes views/dishes/_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@dish) do |f| %>
      <% if @dish.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@dish.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this dish from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @dish.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :nameWoW %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :price %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :price %>
      </div>

  *** The restaurant name field is not being displayed **
      <%= f.fields_for :restaurant do |restaurant| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= restaurant.label :Restname %><br>
          <%= restaurant.text_area :name %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.fields_for :category do |category| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= category.label :Catname %><br>
          <%= category.text_area :name %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

I have followed steps from rails guide, browsed questions on stackoverflow and read some blog posts as well but havent been able to figure out whats wrong. Some micro level mistake is blocking me :( . Anyone knows whats wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE:

Hey I found a solution.

```
 def new
    @dish = Dish.new
    @dish.build_category
    @dish.category.build_restaurant
  end
```

This works well.But this is just a part of the actual solution. I had to do lot of /dish/create controller modification as well. I think the entire solution will have to be put in blog post. Otherwise it wont make any sense. I will soon be posting and updating it here.

Comment: Did you ever write that blog post?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your dish.rb

```
class Dish
  delegate :restaurant, to: :category
end
```

Or you can do

```
  <%= f.fields_for :restaurant, @dish.category.restaurant do |restaurant| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= restaurant.label :Restname %><br>
      <%= restaurant.text_area :name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: the approaches didn't work out of the box. after 1st approach, the field was still missing. In dish#new controller, I modified it to this
```def new@dish = Dish.new
    category = @dish.build_category
    restaurant = @dish.build_restaurant
end
```

2nd Approach, broke a lot of things

Comment: `restaurant = @dish.build_restaurant` won't work as such, still you need to do `@dish = Dish.new
    category = @dish.build_category
    restaurant = category.build_restaurant`

Comment: I dont really think ```restaurant = category.build_restaurant``` does anything to the @dish object. It didn't work earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74048/discussion-between-archit-gupta-and-mayur-rokade).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing:

```
class Dish
  belongs_to :restaurant, through: :category
end
```

You have it on the other side (many) but not there. You could test this by trying to output @dish.restaurant on your form (should be empty but not nil).

Comment: Hey I tried your solution but it didnt work coz ```belongs_to through``` is not valid. I checked this from rails guide in the very beginning itself.

Comment: If i just add ```belongs_to :restaurant``` in Dish model , I am asked to create a migration for a foreign key from Dish to Restaurant which defeats the purpose of Category model as a through table. 

Yes, adding add ```belongs_to :restaurant``` and creating a migration works fine but doesn't look elegant from a DB schema perspective. Not sure if I am expecting too much elegance.

Answer (score 0):

```
def new
  # I think this is where
  # I am making a mistake
  @dish = Dish.new
  category = @dish.category.build
  restaurant = category.restuarant.build
end
```

Comment: category**.build** and category.restaurant**.build** gave me this error ```NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass```

Comment: try restaurant = category.restaurants.new  in your controller

Comment: Hey I found a solution. ```@dish.build_category``` and then ```@dish.category.build_restaurant```. This works well.